# Porting console based ui to a GUI one?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, console

As most of you experienced, developing a console app is as easy as:

```
void mainloop(){
    while (1){
        giveInstructions();
        getInput();
        if (!process()) break;
        printOutput();
    }
}

int main(){
    mainloop();
    return 0;
}
```

However, in GUI it becomes an issue.

We can still `giveInstructions()`, `process()`, and `printOutput()`, but `getInput()` wouldn't work because it relies on an event, usually button click or key down.

How can I port a console app to a gui app with minimum code changes? (preferably do not change the `main` method, and as little change to the `mainloop` function as possible)

Note: I'm not too comfortable with threading yet.

Comment: This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense as written. If you want to use a console app, use a console app.

Comment: You might use a console app to prototype, but your real app is a GUI app, but you don't necessarily want to rewrite the `getInput`, as it might be long and ugly.

Comment: What, in your mind, is the dividing line between a console app and a GUI app?

Comment: Well, console apps are ones that usually has a very simple `while(true)` loop. (I realize that GUI has the same thing, but the ones in console are much simpler). http://packages.python.org/greenlet/ might clear it up (under 1.1 Examples)

Comment: And what would a ported-from-console-app look like?

Comment: Let's say you had to type a command named run something. This time you would have a textbox, with a button beside it saying run. You would then type something into the textbox and hit run.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no specific language given, I will show an example in C# where you would be able to use the same code as the console app with a simple GUI.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //using form-editor, double-click buttons or use the following
            btnInput.Click += new EventHandler(btnInput_Click);
            btnContinue.Click += new EventHandler(btnContinue_Click);
            giveInstructions();
        }

        private void giveInstructions()
        {
            txtInfo.Text = "";
            txtInput.Text = "";
            //display instructions to multi-line textbox
        }

        private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //or you can just add another button for exit.
            if (txtInput.Text == "expected value for exit")
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                getInput();
            }
        }

        private void getInput()
        {
            string strInput = txtInput.Text;
            //do stuff

            printOutput();
        }

        private void printOutput()
        {
            //display output to multi-line textbox
        }

        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            giveInstructions();
        }
    }
```